# Sorting ggplot2 plot after a secondary variable while maintaining facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a plot which shows 6 plots for a variable called trial (called Base1, Base2, etc) for a variable called load. With 3 loads.
To besser compare them I want to have Base 1 of each load (1,3,5) next to each other. Same with Base 2 and so on.
I can't figure out how to sort by trial while still maintaining individual plots for each load condition.
Anyone got any ideas?
Here's my R code:

```
# do the same as boxplot
load_all_base6_pm6_load_boxplot <- load_all_vp_avg_load |>
  dplyr::filter(trial != "" & trial != "Practice") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = trial, y = avg_color_angle_abs_deviation, fill = trial)) +
  geom_boxplot() +  # Use geom_boxplot to create a boxplot
  geom_point(aes(x = trial, y = avg_color_angle_abs_deviation), color = "black", size = 2) +
  labs(x = "Trial load 5", y = "Average Color Angle Deviation abs") +  # Add axis labels
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap( ~ load, labeller = labeller(load = function(variable) paste("Load", variable)))

load_all_base6_pm6_load_boxplot <- load_all_base6_pm6_load_boxplot +
  geom_text(data = load_all_vp_avg_load %>%
              dplyr::filter(trial != "" & trial != "Practice") %>%
              dplyr::filter(avg_color_angle_abs_deviation %in% outliers_all),
            aes(x = trial, y = avg_color_angle_abs_deviation, label = url_code),
            vjust = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~ load, labeller = labeller(load = function(variable) paste("Load", variable)))
```

Tried the creating a order
`desired_order <- c("Base1", "Base2", "Base3")`

and implementing it
`load_all_vp_avg_load$trial <- factor(load_all_vp_avg_load$trial, levels = desired_order)`

I tried using reorder
`ggplot(aes(x = reorder(trial, trial),  y = avg_color_angle_abs_deviation, fill = trial)) +`

However this only sorts them min to max

[This is how it looks atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weVNc.png)

Comment: If you want the three loads for each trial side by side, then how about mapping `load` on `x` and instead facet by `trial`? For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared using `dput()` or using a built-in dataset.